# Функция arrayCopy()

Tags: массивы, c

Где то прячется ошибка, подтолкните на путь истинный ))

```
void arrayCopy(int destination[], int source[], int size) {
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
        destination[i] = source[j];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Вы в своем коде сделали `size * size` операций, хотя должны были сделать только `size` операций:*

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    destination[i] = source[i];
}
```

---

Как упражнение *(и с учетом вашего предыдущего вопроса)* можете попробовать оформить функцию, производяющую копирования из массива `source` в массив `dest`, когда заданы величины `sourceSize` и `destSize`. Упражнение здесь, понятно, **на обработку ситуаций, когда длины не совпадают.**

Comment: Спасибо за совет) Не подскажете где можно о массивах и функциях почитать?

Comment: @arcs_host Не уверен, лучший ли это вариант, но в университетах у нас обычно учат по **"Керниган, Ритчи - Язык программирования С".**

Comment: Для певоначального изучения С, ИМХО, K&R не очень подходит

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования памяти есть специальная функция memcpy. С ней можно переписать твою функцию так:

```
void arrayCopy(int destination[], int source[], int size)
{
    memcpy(destination, source, size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: У автора вопроса конкретное учебное задание, все нужно реализовать ручками. Кроме того, memcpy изнутри примерно так и устроена. Только , кажется, в glibc копирование идет побайтно, а следовательно, будет работать медленнее.

Comment: В метках не написано, что это учебное задание. Откуда такая информация? У меня в Visual Studio memcpy работает на 10% быстрее, чем ручное копирование целыми числами. Там наверное есть ещё какие-то оптимизации. К тому же они там intrinsic.

Comment: Ежику ясно, что задание учебное. К работе человека с такими знаниями вряд ли бы подпустили.

Насчет оптимизации - Вы, кажется, правы. Посмотрел текст glibc, там при небольшом объеме идет копирование тупо по байтам, а при большом производятся какие-то манипуляции со страницами памяти.